# Modify request body in spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, xss, spring-boot-actuator

I want to implement a WebFilter with Spring 5 to modify the request body by filtering XSS.

I have tried different approaches but none of them works.

The Idea is that i need to do might look like this (this code is completely wrong but ...):

```
serverWebExchange
.getRequest
.getBody()
.next()
.flatMap(data -> {
   /* modify data object here */
   return chain.filter(serverWebExchange);
});
```

Any ideas, i tried to search the internet for such a solution, but couldn't found even one.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Actually no, I decided to bypass modifying the request for the sake of XSS handling through the API Gateway.

Comment: Have you tried ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory ?

Comment: Were you able to implement this?